# Special topological equivalence

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems

Are there known examples of a smooth ($C^{\infty}$) or analytic autonomous ordinary differential equation $\dot{x}=f(x,y)$, $\dot{y}=g(x,y)$ in the upper half-plane $\{y\geqslant 0\}$ such that the phase portrait of this equation and that of the equation $\dot{x}=f(x,y)$, $\dot{y}=\mu g(x,y)$ (with some $\mu>0$, $\mu\neq 1$) are *not* topologically equivalent (a) in a neighborhood of the origin or (b) in the whole half-plane?

Answer (score 3):

Let us first give an example of such a system on the entire plane. Consider the linear system
$$\tag{1}
\left\{
\begin{array}{lrr}
\dot x_1=&-x_1&-\frac12 x_2\\
\dot x_2=&3x_1&+x_2.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Since the eigenvalues of the matrix of the system are $\pm \frac1{\sqrt2}i$, the phase portrait of (1) is a center. Let $\mu=2$; consider the "half-scaled" system
$$\tag{2}
\left\{
\begin{array}{lrr}
\dot x_1=&-x_1&-\frac12 x_2\\
\dot x_2=&6x_1&+2x_2.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
The eigenvalues of the matrix of the system are now $\frac12\pm \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$, so the phase portrait of (2) is an unstable focus.

Now, in order to obtain a similar system defined in the upper half-plane, lets make a change of variables $y_1=x_1$, $y_2=e^{x_2}$:
$$\tag{3}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\dot y_1= \dot x_1=-x_1-\frac12 x_2=-y_1-\frac12 \ln y_2 \\
\dot y_2= e^{x_2} \dot x_2=y_2\left( 3y_1+\ln y_2 \right)
\end{array}
\right.
$$
System (3) is the desired system. Its trajectories are closed orbits, while the trajectories of the corresponding "half-scaled" system (it can be obtained from (2) using the same change of variables)
$$\tag{4}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\dot y_1= -y_1-\frac12 \ln y_2 \\
\dot y_2= 2y_2\left( 3y_1+\ln y_2 \right)
\end{array}
\right.
$$
are not closed.

Let us now construct a similar system defined in a closed upper half-plane. To do this, we need one specially constructed smooth function.
Let $f(x)$ be the [non-analytic smooth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) on $[0,+\infty)$
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}&\text{if }x>0,\\ 0&\text{if }x\le0.\end{cases}
$$
Further, [as shown in the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#Smooth_transition_functions), we build a smooth transition function
$$
g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}
$$
The next function we build will be
$$
h(x)= \int_0^{x} g(t)\,dt.
$$
Here is the graph of this function:
[image: h(x)]

This is almost what we need. It remains to "move" it a little
(note that $h(1)=\frac12$), introducing
$$
\varphi(x)= h\left(x+\frac14\right)+\frac14.
$$
Here is the graph of this function:
[image: \varphi(x)]

This function is smooth, positive for any $x$ and it coincides with $x$ for $x\ge\frac34$.

Now we modify the system (4) by "neutralizing" the logarithm:
$$\tag{5}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\dot y_1= -y_1-\frac12 \ln (\varphi(y_2)) \\
\dot y_2= y_2\left( 3y_1+\ln (\varphi(y_2)) \right)
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Note that the line $y_2=0$ is an invariant manifold and we can exclude the lower half-plane from the domain. In some neighborhood of the equilibrium point $(0;1)$ the system (5) has closed trajectories, while the "half-scaled" system (6) doesn't.
$$\tag{6}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\dot y_1= -y_1-\frac12 \ln (\varphi(y_2)) \\
\dot y_2= 2y_2\left( 3y_1+\ln (\varphi(y_2)) \right)
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I asked. I need systems defined in the closed upper half-plane $\{y_2\geqslant 0\}$, not in the open one $\{y_2>0\}$.

Comment: @V.V.Veskatov I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks! Of course, I'd also like an analytic example, but it seems that new ideas are needed for this.

Answer (score 2):

Two exceedingly simple analytic examples are presented in the paper: M.B.Sevryuk. Three examples in the dynamical systems theory. Symmetry, Integrability and Geometry: Methods and Applications (SIGMA), 2022, v. 18, 084 (13 pages), https://doi.org/10.3842/SIGMA.2022.084, see also https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.02620.